# Create a multidimensional array from 1-D list, numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

Struggling to describe this issue in words, but have a seemingly simple issue I can't find an answer for.

I want to create an array using values from one list/array and indices from another. I want the shape of the new array to be the same as the index array.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2])

b = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]

result = func(a, b) #some function or operator...

print(result)
[[9, 8], [7, 6, 5], [3, 2, 1, 0, -1]]
```

Thank you! :)

EDIT:

Good solutions so far, but I would rather do this without a for loop as we are looking at hundreds of thousands of rows and need to keep computing time down. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [a[x[0]:x[-1]+1] for x in b]
[array([9, 8]), array([7, 6, 5]), array([ 3,  2,  1,  0, -1])]
```

EDIT: Your question indicates that you want a faster option, so you might test the following script to see which is faster for your Python installation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                               

import timeit

setup = '''                                                                         
import numpy as np                                                                  

a = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2])                                
b = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]                                           
'''

test1 = '''                                                                         
def test():                                                                         
  return [a[x[0]:x[-1]+1] for x in b]                                               
'''

test2 = '''                                                                         
def test():                                                                         
  return [a[idx] for idx in b]                                                      
'''

print(timeit.timeit(setup = setup,
                    stmt = test1,
                    number = 1000000))

print(timeit.timeit(setup = setup,
                    stmt = test2,
                    number = 1000000))
```

On my machine, the two approaches given you so far run about the same, but hpaulj's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54192781/19410) might be very slightly faster (unless Python is caching data behind the scenes), which may be of more use to you in production. Test it out locally and see if you get a similar or different answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply each indexing sublist to `a`:

```
In [483]: a = np.array([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2])
     ...: 
     ...: b = [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [484]: [a[idx] for idx in b]
Out[484]: [array([9, 8]), array([7, 6, 5]), array([ 3,  2,  1,  0, -1])]
```

The sublists differ in length, so the result cannot be made into a 2d array - it has to remain a list (or if you insist 1d object dtype array).